# WCF/Rest/UriTemplate variable length query string parameter list?

Tags: wcf, rest, variables, parameters, uritemplate

WCF will match this:

http://localhost:8888/test/blahFirst/blahSecond/sdfsdf,wwewe

to this:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet( UriTemplate = "test/{first}/{second}/{val1},{val2}" )]
string GetVal( string first, string second, string val1, string val2 );
```

Is there a way to make the va11, val2 be a variable length list of parameters? So it could be val1, ...., valN? And end up with a service method such as:

```
string GetVal( string first, string second, List<string> params );
```

Or something along those lines?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just GET a simple string and then convert it to an Array (or a list) in the method, using the split method.

Your Interface should look something like this:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "test/{first}/{second}/{val1}")]
string GetVal(string first, string second, string val1);
```

Your implementation:

```
public string GetVal(string first, string second, string paramArray)
    {
        string[] parameters = paramArray.Split(',');

        foreach (string parameter in parameters)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(parameter);
        }

        return "Hello";
    }
```

And call it like this in your browser:

```
http://localhost:8731/MyServer/test/first/second/1,2,3
```

[Take a look at the MSDN forum for a detailed answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/2341c11e-92b3-4da4-aba5-858054f46c80)

Comment: Basically I've found the answer to my question is "No, you can't do that directly."  But yes, your method will work. I'll give it a check anyways.